# Why does Marionette ItemView.open call $el.empty() after just rendering steps before?

Tags: javascript, marionette

Why does Marionette ItemView.open call $el.empty() after just rendering steps before?

After much gnashing of teeth because my ItemView wouldn't show up I stepped through the marionette code.  To my very happy surprise my ItemView **was** rendering.
 Here is part of ItemView.show:

```
       show: function(view){

        this.ensureEl();

        if (view !== this.currentView) {
            this.close();
            view.render();  // <-- Much rejoicing! It showed up!
            this.open(view);
```

Cool, so I hit continue on the debugger and bam! my view was gone.  It turns out it was getting clobbered in the open() method:

```
// Override this method to change how the new view is
// appended to the `$el` that the region is managing
   open: function(view){
        this.$el.empty().append(view.el);
   },
```

SO there it is $el.empty().  I see that I can override it, but I have another app that this doesn't happen to.  So looking at the code for empty():

```
// Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
   if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
       jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) ); //<-- Much sadness it disappeared. :(
   }
```

Anyone know what a nodeType ===1 means?  It seems my app that works isn't nodeType===1 where my current app with the disappearing ItemView is nodeType===1

Any suggestions on what I should do?

1. Override open?  With what? I don't really know Marionette well enough to have the confidence that I won't break something else.
2. Set nodeType to something besides 1?  What other setting?
3. Your suggestion here? :)

Comment: [MDN Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) should explain what `elem.nodeType === 1` does - it checks to see if `elem` is in fact a tag in the DOM. Also, `ItemView` doesn't have a `show` method. Can you post the code you're using to render the itemview?

Comment: It would help if you put up a jsFiddle. I'd venture to guess you're doing some custom things with render and/or show.

Comment: Ok so I double checked my app that works.  It is also a nodeType ===1 so that is not the problem.  It looks like once the el is emptied the view passed into open is then used to repopulate the el.  The one that works just like that.  The app that doesn't work has the innerHTML set correctly coming into open but after empty is called the passed in view's innerHtml is "".  Not sure how that happened.

Comment: @DavidSulc I don't have a render or show method of my own. I trigger an event to show "App.vent.trigger('app:show:content', App.Views.homeView);"   and I catch that event with "App.vent.on('app:show:content', function(view) {
            App.content.show(view);
        });"  Showing on my region passing in my view.  Still working on a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I removed one line from my view and it worked as advertised.  The line I removed?

```
// The DOM Element associated with this view
el: ".center_court",
```

That is also region = content === .center_court. 
With App.content.show(view) I was sending the view to itself.  So now the View doesn't need to know what it's el is.   By default it uses a div and that will show up fine in my region.

Thanks for looking at this, hopefully it will help someone.

Andrew